# What features would a *perfect* Python debugger have?

Tags: python, ide, debugging

Please tell me which features you wish your current Python debugger had. I'm creating a new Python IDE/debugger and am looking forward to challenging requests!

Comment: The ability to read my mind and debug the code for me :)

Answer (score 6):

Forgive me for the shameless functional programming plug, but...

The ability to *step backwards*.

Answer (score 6):

I use [winpdb](http://winpdb.org/) and I like it very much. I think a new debugger would need to have at least its features. It has some GUI nuisiances though, so maybe you fix it or take some ideas from it to write your own.

[Winpdb](http://winpdb.org/) is a **platform independent** graphical GPL Python debugger with support for remote debugging over a network, multiple threads, namespace modification, embedded debugging, encrypted communication and is up to 20 times faster than pdb.

Features:

- GPL license. Winpdb is Free Software.
- Compatible with CPython 2.3 through 2.6 and Python 3000
- Compatible with wxPython 2.6 through 2.8
- Platform independent, and tested on Ubuntu Gutsy and Windows XP.
- User Interfaces: rpdb2 is console based, while winpdb requires wxPython 2.6 or later.

[image: Screenshot]
<sub>(source: [winpdb.org](http://winpdb.org/images/screenshot_winpdb_small.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Last time I try winpdb (about half years ago), winpdb has all feature I want. But I feel its user interface need refine (I am not talking beautiful looking. What I mean is about hotkey, layout, default dialog position, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

The #1 debug feature for me (that my current IDE, Wing, does happen to have) is the ability to drop into a python interpreter and run arbitrary python code when at a breakpoint.  Reminds me of using Smalltalk back in the day.

Ability to execute code in local scope is incredibly useful, especially in contrast to working in C++ when it can sometimes be a fight to inspect a local variable.

Comment: I'd love that.  Wing IDE is really impressive.  Wish it was free-er.

Comment: That is what PDB allows you to do anyway, so its nothing extra Wing is giving you. Wing is a good tool, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Ability to step through expression evaluation and intuitive visualization of call stack like in Thonny (http://thonny.org)