# What debuggers are there for python and what are there features?

Tags: python

What debuggers are there for python and what are there features? I have trolled through lots of websites looking for a comparison between the debuggers so far i have found ([What features would a *perfect* Python debugger have?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600401/what-features-would-a-perfect-python-debugger-have)) which is the only help i have had.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pdb is awesome:

```
import pdb
pdb.set_trace() # put this line where the debugger breaks initially
```

step through (goes into functions):

```
>> s
```

continue:

```
>> c
```

show lines around:

```
>> l
```

print a variable "some_var":

```
>> some_var
```

For more information: https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html

Answer (score 0):

Python comes with `pdb`.

See also `ipdb` package, which adds comfort of `iPython` console (syntax highlighting, tab competion...).

Both tools work on command line and might first seem too simple. But if you come through some tutorial for use of them (both being very similar), you will invite the fact, that

- they are available almost anywhere, even on remote Linux console
- provide the service you need

Most other debuggers will add some IDE, where you can be in some editor and perform actions from there. To me it seems, like this could be handy, but the core functionality is already available on command line.

Tip: With `nose` testing framework, you even have a chance to use a switch, which start the debugger at the moment, some test fails. This works for `pdb` as well `ipdb`.

## Conclusions

- Learning debugger for any language is big productivity help. Spending a day learning and practising with it will definitely pay back very soon.
- Command line debuggers provide all you really need, IDE extras are just something above, what is not so crucial. The concepts are still the same.